# am5charts Cannot find HTMLElement with id 'x' React iframe chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, iframe, google-chrome-extension, amcharts, content-script

I try use am5charts inside a chrome extension, content script and is inside a iframe, React.

I try to use useRef() to pass to am5charts the htmlElement.

```
const chartRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();
  useEffect(() => {
    am5.ready(function () {
      const chartDoc = chartRef.current;

      const root = am5.Root.new(chartDoc);
```

chartRef is atached to a div in the return.

tried too `const chartDoc = chartRef.current as HTMLDivElement;`

inside of am5charts is checking if what i pass on `am5.Root.new(chartDoc)` is instanceof HtmlElement but is React FiberNode object...
[screenshot from console debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vetdb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, maybe little bit hacky.

```
const chartRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  useEffect(() => {
    const chartDoc = chartRef.current;

if (chartDoc.childNodes.length > 0) {
  return;
}

const chartDiv = document.createElement('div');
chartDiv.style.height = '275px';

chartDoc.appendChild(chartDiv);

const root = am5.Root.new(chartDiv);
```